# How to create a label on UIVIewController Dynamically in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I m working on one project in which I have to select the user from UITableViewController and then that user name will be added to my UIViewController on UILabel on conditional bases that is

1) first time UIVIewcontroller is clean without any label then viewDidload of UIViewController  will create a label on screen with that name selected from UITableViewController.

2)next time when user select another name from UITableViewController than in viewDidLoad there is conditon that will check is there any label exist if yes then it will create a new one on different X and Y axis I mean in next line.

what code I have to write in viewDidLoad to solve this problem please give me necessary code to implement the above logic.

Please I really need help .

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you are trying to do is not very difficult... That being said, you have asked 14 questions on StackOverflow without marking any of them as answered. If you want people to help you then you should say thank you back to them... If you mark more questions as answered you will be more likely to get help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check on google some tuto like here to make your UILabel programaticaly:
[iPhone Hello World Using UILabel](http://www.forgeniuses.com/2008/03/12/iphone-hello-world-using-uilabel/)

After you have to add some instance variable to your UIViewController to check your different conditions.